# Invoke the “Hello, world!” program failed

Tags: web3.js, transactions

I have a solana program. and i deployed it on devnet `D8NgQm2XmARRz9PLGeD7bWHyp7zYpNqRDEuQXKPc9m19` this is my code .

```
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};

// 指定 Solana 链上程序的入口函数
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

/// 计数器
#[derive(Debug, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub struct GreetingAccount {
    pub counter: u32,
}

/// 作为入口函数必须包含下面的参数和 ProgramResult 返回类型
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    // 将消息写入到 Solana 链上
    msg!("hello solana");
    msg!("终于把环境配置好了啊魂淡！");

    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    if account.owner != program_id {
        // 当前账户才能执行代码
        msg!("账户Id不正确");
        Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId)
    } else {
        let mut greeting_account = GreetingAccount::try_from_slice(&account.data.borrow())?;
        greeting_account.counter += 1;
        greeting_account.serialize(&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
        msg!("打招呼次数：{greeting_account.counter}");
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

My client code like this :

```
const oulaoba = Uint8Array.from([83, 187, 201, 144, 173, 124, 162, 94, 159, 179, 6, 200, 95, 159, 52, 66, 16, 76, 170, 49, 111, 81, 241, 99, 102, 154, 123, 135, 82, 210, 112, 71, 113, 182, 173, 162, 23, 87, 73, 96, 211, 137, 189, 221, 218, 174, 250, 129, 196, 33, 32, 242, 105, 54, 192, 174, 66, 165, 85, 10, 129, 28, 181, 196]);

const programId = new web3.PublicKey("D8NgQm2XmARRz9PLGeD7bWHyp7zYpNqRDEuQXKPc9m19");

const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'));

async function sayHello(): Promise<web3.TransactionSignature> {

  const payer = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(oulaoba);

  const transaction = new web3.Transaction()

  const instruction = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [],
    programId,
  })

  transaction.add(instruction)

  const transactionSignature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [payer]
  )

  return transactionSignature
}
```

When i run client code , i got an error
`Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: insufficient account keys for instruction at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction` 
I just wanne request my solana program ,and success .
What should i do . help plz.

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing and `AccountMeta` objects to the `keys` field of the `TransactionInstruction` constructor, which is why you're getting an insufficient account keys error.

It looks like your instruction expects a program account to be passed in that is deserializable as a `GreetingAccount` type account but is clearly never provided to the program during instruction invocation.

Would need to update the constructor call to be something like:

```
const instruction = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
  keys: [{ pubkey: programAccountPubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }],
  programId,
})
```

depending on the needs of the instruction.

Comment: I don’t know what should I do , I tried the way ,but still have the same error . the `programAccountPubkey` is my programId `D8NgQm2XmARRz9PLGeD7bWHyp7zYpNqRDEuQXKPc9m19` ? or another account's Pubkey ?

Answer (score 0):

I find my mistakes , my solana program can’t run well .isn’t a bad code. And when i changed it simple ,just keep `msg!()` and `OK(())` my request is successful ,and i can see the msg on solana Explore `https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5pBGCwrZaP7NqZPbpXNpwYrgekvPCiEm14BTLtZuTE5fttSHsoTMy3EnwgHaCDrmxxjQ38488KgQ887VhAi228TQ?cluster=devnet`.

my solana programId is `NdtjKAwwQAvtug2JBGt1UXkEZuJ5xdz3GuTVPXYwkqB` . in case  somebody like me,you can invoke my program .

Hope it useful for you .